# T-SQL RegEx Matching "One or More" Operator

Tags: sql, regex, python-3.x

In MS SQL, is there an operator that allows the matching of one or more character? (I'm curious about whether its implemented explicitly in T-SQL - other solutions are certainly possible, one of which I use in my question example below . . .)

I know in SQL, this could be explicitly implemented to varying degrees of success with the wildcard/like approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
-- finds letters aix and then anything following it
WHERE column LIKE 'aix_x%'
```

In Python, the '+' operator allows for this:

```
import re

str = "The rain in Spain falls mainly in the plain!"

#Check if the string contains "ai" followed by 1 or more "x" characters:
# finds 'ai' + one or more letters x
x = re.findall("aix+", str)

print(x)

if (x):
  print("Yes, there is at least one match!")
else:
  print("No match")
```

Comment: SQL Server does not have full regular expression support.  You may find that doing this in Python is simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Check if the string contains "ai" followed by 1 or more "x" characters:
>   finds 'ai' + one or more letters x

If this is what you want, then:

where str like '%aix%'

does what you want.

If you want an underscore, then an  underscore is a wildcard in `LIKE` expressions.  Probably the simplest method in SQL Server is to use a character class:

where str like '%ai[_]x%'

another solution is:

where str like '%ai$_x%' escape '$'